# Random Guessing Game in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My assignment is to create a guessing game where the computer guesses my number and one where I guess the computer's number. I have my code written out but It's incomplete. I want to create a menu so the user can choose which game he wants to play, and also i am having trouble joining the two programs into one so they both will run. Can someone please assist me. The first game works fine but from there I really don't know what I'm doing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int min = 1;
    const int max = 100;
    int num = 2 && 3 && 4;
    int prevMin = 0;
    int prevMax = 0;
    int tries = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    int userNum = 0;
    int userGuess = 0;
    int systemNum = 0;
    int systemGuess = 0;



    cout << "Welcome to the Guessing Game!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a 2 to play Game 1 or a 3 to play Game 2. Or enter 4 to quit." << endl;
    cin >> num;

    if (num == 2)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Game 1!" << endl;
        cout << "User, enter a random number between " << min << " and " << max << " : "; cin >> userNum;
    }


    srand(time(0));
    systemGuess = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do
    {
        cout << "System, guess the user's number between " << min << " and " << max << ": " << systemGuess << endl;
        cin.get();
        ++tries;
        if (systemGuess > max || systemGuess<min)
        {
            cout << "I said guess a number between " << min << " and " << max << " stupid." << endl;
        }

        if (systemGuess > userNum)
        {
            cout << "Too high. Guess lower." << endl;
            prevMax = systemGuess;

            systemGuess = rand() % (prevMax - prevMin) + prevMin;

            if (systemGuess == prevMin)
                systemGuess++;
        }

        else if (systemGuess < userNum)
        {
            cout << "Too low. Guess higher." << endl;
            prevMin = systemGuess;

            systemGuess = rand() % (prevMax - prevMin) + prevMin;

            if (systemGuess == prevMin)
                systemGuess++;
        }




    } while (systemGuess != userNum);

    cout << systemGuess << endl;
    cout << " I guessed it right! It took me " << tries << " guess(es). " << endl;




    srand(time(0));
    systemNum = rand()% 100 + 1;




    //Beginning of second game

    do
    {
        if (num == 3)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Game 2!" << endl;
        cout << "User, try to guess the computer's number that's between " << min << " and " << max << " . " << endl;
    }


        cout << "Enter your guess." << endl;
        cin >> userGuess;
        tries++;

        if (userGuess > systemNum)
        {
            cout << "Too high. Guess lower." << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }
        else if (userGuess < systemNum)
        {
            cout << "Too low. Guess higher." << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Correct! It took you long enough! Lol... " << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }
        while (userGuess != systemNum);

    }







    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Not related to answer be I would prefer: Enter a "2" to play Game-1 or a "3" to play Game-2. Or enter "4" to quit. Just so it doesn't confuse the user.

Comment: Ok, the only thing I'm really trying to do is make the actual menu work. but I don't know how.

Comment: You want the menu and when the user inputs 2 to go to game1 or 3 to go to game2 and exit once the user enters 4 or when either of the games are over?

Comment: Yes exactly that, and also show the best score(guess) during the time he or she was playing that particular game once they exit.

Answer (score 0):

Make the two games two distinct functions (each with its own local variables), create a third one that is a loop that prompts for the games (and break when "quit" is selected), and call the corresponding function, then call the third one from main.

Comment: I wish I could say that I know what you are talking about but I can't. This is only my third week coding and I'm just steadily trying to learn at the rate of some of my peers.

Comment: He means don't stuff all your code into main but break it up into modules

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if...else` :

```
    cout << "Welcome to the Guessing Game!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a 2 to play Game 1 or a 3 to play Game 2. Or enter 4 to quit." << endl;
    cin >> num;

if (num == 2)
{//game1
}
else if(num==3)
{//game2
}
else if(num==4)
{return 0;
}else
{
cout<<"Invalid choice!";
system("pause");
return 1;
}
//print highscores
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Your whole code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int min = 1;
    const int max = 100;
    int num = 2 && 3 && 4;
    int prevMin = 0;
    int prevMax = 0;
    int tries = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    int userNum = 0;
    int userGuess = 0;
    int systemNum = 0;
    int systemGuess = 0;
        srand(time(0));


    cout << "Welcome to the Guessing Game!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a 2 to play Game 1 or a 3 to play Game 2. Or enter 4 to quit." << endl;
    cin >> num;

    if (num == 2)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Game 1!" << endl;
        cout << "User, enter a random number between " << min << " and " << max << " : "; cin >> userNum;


    systemGuess = rand() % 100 + 1;

    do
    {
        cout << "System, guess the user's number between " << min << " and " << max << ": " << systemGuess << endl;
        cin.get();
        ++tries;
        if (systemGuess > max || systemGuess<min)
        {
            cout << "I said guess a number between " << min << " and " << max << " stupid." << endl;
        }

        if (systemGuess > userNum)
        {
            cout << "Too high. Guess lower." << endl;
            prevMax = systemGuess;

            systemGuess = rand() % (prevMax - prevMin) + prevMin;

            if (systemGuess == prevMin)
                systemGuess++;
        }

        else if (systemGuess < userNum)
        {
            cout << "Too low. Guess higher." << endl;
            prevMin = systemGuess;

            systemGuess = rand() % (prevMax - prevMin) + prevMin;

            if (systemGuess == prevMin)
                systemGuess++;
        }




    } while (systemGuess != userNum);

    cout << systemGuess << endl;
    cout << " I guessed it right! It took me " << tries << " guess(es). " << endl;
    }



    systemNum = rand()% 100 + 1;


//Beginning of second game

        if (num == 3)
    {
    do
    {

        cout << "Welcome to Game 2!" << endl;
        cout << "User, try to guess the computer's number that's between " << min << " and " << max << " . " << endl;



        cout << "Enter your guess." << endl;
        cin >> userGuess;
        tries++;

        if (userGuess > systemNum)
        {
            cout << "Too high. Guess lower." << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }
        else if (userGuess < systemNum)
        {
            cout << "Too low. Guess higher." << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Correct! It took you long enough! Lol... " << endl;
            cin >> userGuess;
        }}
        while (userGuess != systemNum);


    }else if(num==4)return 0;    
else{
cout<<"Invalid choice!";
system("pause");
return 1;
}

//print highscores


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm still having errors and the program only runs through the first game, and the menu still does not work.

Comment: @JatoriGraves ,I'll post the whole code. Its supposed to work.

Comment: Alright, I need to practice coding everyday to actually know it.

Comment: @JatoriGraves , Yeah ! Try the code in my answer and accept the answer if it helped !

Comment: That did help, but I still have to debug game 2.It only lets me guess twice before it displays "User, try to guess the computer's number...". I'll see if I can figure it out though.

Comment: @JatoriGraves , Accept the answer since it answered your question. As for the game2 , remove all the cin from the body of if,else if and else